# iOS display image on a popover depending on the UIButton clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uiimageview, popover

This is what I am trying to do:

[image: screenshot]

On clicking the 'info (i)' button I need to display a popover with an image on the left and some associated text to its right.

Now let's call the view in the background as 'View 1' and the popover as 'View 2'.

Here is what the View2Controller.h looks like:

```
@class View2Controller;
@protocol View2ControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)infoPopover:(View2Controller *)obic loadImage: (NSString *)imageFilename;

@end

@interface View2Controller : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageInfo;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textInfo;

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<View2ControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end

id <View2ControllerDelegate> _delegate;
```

Now the View1Controller.h has this line:

```
@interface View1Controller : UIViewController <View2ControllerDelegate>
```

And the @implementation of View1Controller.m looks somewhat like this

```
- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender {
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;

View2Controller *obic = [[View2Controller alloc]init];
[obic setDelegate:self];

switch (btn.tag) {
    case 1:
        [self infoPopover:obic loadImage:@"info1.png"];
        break;

    case 2:
        //Info View 2
        break;

    case 3:
        //Info View 3
        break;

    case 4:
        //Info View 4
        break;

    case 5:
        //Info View 5
        break;

    case 6:
        //Info View 6
        break;


    default:
        break;
}
}
```

and

```
- (void)infoPopover:(View2Controller *)obic loadImage:(NSString *)imageFilename
{
    [obic.imageInfo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageFilename]];
}
```

I have looked up several tutorials on how delegates work. But i still can't display the image 'info1.png' on the 'UIImageView imageinfo'. Any comments are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your problem is probably how you create obic with alloc init. This is most likely creating a new instance of View2Controller, not accessing the one you already have. You need to explain how your 2 controllers are created, and what the overall hierarchy of your controllers is (are they in a navigation controller, split view, etc.).

Comment: I just segue from View1Controller to View2Controller using 'popover' once the 'i' button is clicked.

I just realized View1Controller (along with a few other controllers) are embedded in a navigation controller but View2Controller is not. Should View2Controller be embedded in the Navigation controller as well??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!!

As suggested before by Paulw11 delegate was not the way to go in the first place. So I took the delegate code out. I also took out IBAction showinfo. Instead I used the method:

```
-(BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{
   if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"info"]) {
        UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setInteger:btn.tag forKey:@"infoButton"];
}
return YES;
```

in View1Controller and in the View2Controller I added :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *imageArray = @[@"info1.png", @"info2.png", @"info3.png", @"info4.png", @"info5.png", @"info6.png"];
    int infoButtonChoice = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"infoButton"];

    [self.imageInfo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageArray[infoButtonChoice -1]]];
}
```

and that makes the app work exactly as I want!!

Comment: Passing your button number via NSUserDefaults is a bit of an overkill. Simply add an integer property to View2Controller and set it in shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier.  You should also move your image setting to `viewWillAppear` rather than `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a pop over segue linked to your info button then you don't need to create a `View2Controller` - the segue will do that for you.

You can get rid of the showInfo IBAction method and add a `prepareForSegue:` method -

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    View2Controller *obic=(View2Controller)segue.destinationViewController;
    obic.delegate=self;

    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;


    NSString *imageFilename=nil;

    switch (btn.tag) {
    case 1:
        imageFilename=@"info1.png";
        break;

    case 2:
        //Info View 2
        break;

    case 3:
        //Info View 3
        break;

    case 4:
        //Info View 4
        break;

    case 5:
        //Info View 5
        break;

    case 6:
        //Info View 6
        break;


    default:
        break;
   }

   if (image!=nil)
   { 
       [obic.imageInfo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageFilename]];
   }
   else
   {
       NSLog(@"Unknown button tag triggered segue - %d",btn.tag);
   }
}
```

Also nothing you have shown here requires View1Controller to act as a delegate for View2Controller, so perhaps you are misunderstanding what delegation is used for.  Say there was a button in View2Controller that you wanted to notify View1Controller when it was pressed - in View2Controller you could call `[self.delegate theButtonWasPressed];` and this would call that method in whatever the delegate was (which could be a View1Controller instance that implemented the View2ControllerDelegate protocol)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Paulw11 but the code you suggested did not work. As you instructed, I removed the 'delegate' code and commented out the IBAction showinfo. I also removed the connection between the 'info' button and View2Controller (which I had initially created). I did this following your comment on the segue creating a ViewController for me. On running the code, the press of the 'info' button does not do anything.

Comment: No, you need the connection between the info button and a  View2Controller scene in your storyboard - that is the segue that is triggered when you touch the button